# Not Able to retrieve data from a database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am not able to retrieve data from my database in android.When i try to retrieve data it just returns a blank value..any idea what is causing the error..i have attached the code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exp3);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        final String name=e1.getText().toString();
        final String number=e2.getText().toString();
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Students.db",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studentdb(rollno VARCHAR,name VARCHAR);");
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO STUDENTDB VALUES('"+name+"','"+number+"');");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully inserted the entry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM STUDENTDB", null);
                StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer(); 
                while(c.moveToNext())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                tv.setText(buffer.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row has an empty value.

This is because the variables `name` and `number` are read in `onCreate`, when the two EditTexts do not yet contain a value.

You must read these values only when the button is clicked, i.e., in the `onClick` method.

Comment: But he doesnt use those values in `b2` (`SELECT` query)

Comment: But when inserting. The values in the DB are wrong.

Comment: But he doesnt ask that...(no offense) :)

Comment: He asks why he can't retrieve the data. The answer is that the data wasn't inserted in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to call `moveToFirst` method :

```
 Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM STUDENTDB", null);
 c.moveToFirst(); //here
 StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer(); 
 while(c.moveToNext())
 {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 tv.setText(buffer.toString());
```

Comment: I added c.movetofirst()..but still i get the error..when i try to toast the first column values i get a blank value.

Comment: Please post your logcat :)

Comment: i don't get an error...what i mean is toast just displays a blank value.

Comment: debug the cursor and see whats wrong, i cant find it with my bare eyes

Comment: The first `moveToNext()` call will go to the first row (if any). With this code, the first row would be skipped.

Comment: @CL. sorry what do you mean? so he doesnt need to do ` c.moveToFirst();` ?

Comment: No; a simple `while (c.moveToNext())` loop is perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to call `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` after the insertion to commit the records to the database

Comment: i tried this..the program stopped unexpectedly...it gave the error cannot perform because there is no current transaction

Comment: This would be needed only after `beginTransaction()`.